# Referencing an array from a function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I writing a code for a clock and I'm creating a function to display the time which is stored in an array time[]

```
char time[]="23:59:45         ";
char display_time(char *t[], char *, char *, char *);

void main(void)             
{
            display_time(&time, &hr, &min, &sec);
            GLCD_GoTo(5,3);
            GLCD_WriteString(time, Font_System7x8);
}
```

and this is my function

```
char display_time(char *t[], char *h, char *m, char *s)
{

                *t[0]=*h/10+48;
                *t[1]=*h%10+48;
                *t[3]=*m/10+48;
                *t[4]=*m%10+48;
                *t[6]=*s/10+48;
                *t[7]=*s%10+48;


}
```

Everything compiles fine but my time isn't getting update and only the initialized value is being displayed.

Comment: If you learned `void main(void)` in class, it's time to switch lecturers.

Comment: Increase your compiler warning level to the max .. and **mind the warnings**

Comment: You never show your code that is supposed to actually update the time. I'm assuming somewhere you actually modify the values in time[], you should post your code that does this, so we can actually see what may be going wrong.

Comment: Like I said no warnings no errors it just doesn't do what I expect it to do

Comment: @KerrekSB not sure, but "GLCD" maybe is a "LCD" related function. Maybe there is no environment to return something.

Comment: @Jarek The code works fine when I update the time in my main function but I want to do this in a defined function (display_time) which is when it stopped working

Comment: The order of operations in that code makes me dizzy.

Comment: Also, why are you passing everything by address (and mutably, too)?

Comment: @Amanni what are `hr`, `min`, and `sec`?

Comment: @sidyll: That'd still be ill-formed C (in a hosted environment).

Comment: @ Jonathan..I'm working with real time systems and it helps with accuracy     @Sidyll those are variables for hour sec and min like I wrote earlier there's a long piece of code to calculate these but everything worked fine when I just updated the array in my main function but I need to have it in a defined function

Comment: You probably meant to call your function like this: `display_time(time, &hr, &min, &sec);` - no ampersand on time.

Comment: @tinman...thanks alot, that sorted it out. You should answer the question so I can mark it as the correct answer also can you explain why its different for the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- please compile with warnings (gcc -Wall -Wextra)
- display_time should return void
- main should return int and take either `(int, char*[])` or `()`, but NOT `(void)`
- you can improve the lisibility by passing values (instead of pointers)
- use `'0'` instead of 48, again for lisibility
- you did not initialize hr. min and sec in your code.
- you should test if h is between 0 and 24 etc.
- you should test for NULL pointer
- `display_time` doesn't "display time", write a better name for the function and you're done :-)

.

```
void display_time(char t[], int h, int m, int s) {
    t[0] = h / 10 + '0';
    t[1] = h % 10 + '0';
    t[3] = m / 10 + '0';
    t[4] = m % 10 + '0';
    t[6] = s / 10 + '0';
    t[7] = s % 10 + '0';
}

int main(int, char*[]) {
    char time[] = "23:59:45";
    int hr = 3, min = 9, sec = 42;
    display_time(time, hr, min, sec);
    GLCD_GoTo(5,3);
    GLCD_WriteString(time, Font_System7x8);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your types are wrong.  You shouldn't be sending `char *t[]`, as you are not passing an array of pointers.  Also, you may not realize but `&time` is the same as `time`, there is no "address of time".  You want to just pass char* to your function.

Comment: What do you mean as `&time` is the same as `time`?

Comment: That's how array declarations work.  Try it, do printf("%x %x", &time, time);, and it will print two identical addresses

Comment: From what I understand, they **are different** because they have different type. `time` is `char[9]` and `&time` is `char*`. The thing in your call to `printf` is that this is a variadic function and you have an implicit cast to int there (because `%x` expects an unsigned hexadecimal integer).

Comment: @GiovanniFunchal, that isn't a functional difference that impacts the  behavior of the posted question.  Under the hood, a char[] and a char* are the same.  My point is that it's wrong to do *t[0], because it should just be t[0]

Comment: No char[] and char* are NOT the same. `char[]` means that there is an array somewhere and indicates its address, but the `char*` means that there is an array somewhere PLUS a pointer to the array and indicate the pointer.

Comment: @GiovanniFunchal, I totally understand what you are saying.  But again, in the context of passing arguments to a function it IS the same.  If you call a function declared with a char* argument or a function with a char[] argument, the exact same thing happens at the assembly level.  In both cases the same pointer is put on the stack.